# Which apps help to find unconventional accommodation?

Tags: cellphones, accommodation, mobile-apps

I have heard of CouchSurfing and Airbnb and I know these services have apps.

Does anyone know of any other apps (only for iPhone / Android phone) available for connecting and finding accommodation, either via hospitality networks, or cheap hotels and hostels?

I am looking for more the bohemian ways to stay rather than hotel searches like TripAdvisor.

Comment: What do you mean by app? For which device / platform? Is a web-site/app also OK for you? In that case there are plenty of offers on the web, such as [Wimdu](http://www.wimdu.com/), a copy of Airbnb.

Comment: No, I'm specifically talking about phone apps.

Comment: For which phone? Many phones can open web-sites/apps as well, and [FirefoxOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_OS) powered phones in fact nothing else.

Comment: What type of accomodation do you need? And what type platform for? TripAdvisor has an app for iOS and, probably, for Android.

Comment: @Evgeniy Indeed, the TripAdvisor app is listed among the top six results when I search for "accommodation" on [Google Play](https://play.google.com).

Comment: from the [faq] - " eliciting list-style answers, suggestions or **recommendations** on a topic or place (unless VERY specific criteria is listed) " is not permitted.  Could you please rephrase the question, so as to avoid it being closed?

Comment: @AndrewWelch which device/platform? Several people have asked this now and it's too broad as it stands - as someone said in the chat, what if there's an app on a Symbian platform, it'd be useless to you?

Comment: Closing for now until the comments are addressed, at present it's not constructive and too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Hostelworld has apps](http://www.hostelworld.com/mobile-landing)  for iPhones and Androids, as a well as a
  mobile-optimised website.
- [Couchsurfing has mobile apps](https://www.couchsurfing.org/n/mobile) too but because of the model Couchsurfing works on, this isn't for "booking" accommodation in anyway.

What you'll find that "unconventional" accommodation typically does not lend itself to be easily integrated into software-based inventory management systems (or at least cannot afford the cost of standardisation / development work yet) and hence the reason why you are far likelier to find apps to search "normal" types of accommodation.